# KnockoutJS - data-bind wont change text after button click

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have been struggling for a few days with knockout data binding.
The simple yet very annoying example of problem that I struggle with is down below.

I have a simple ViewModel class with a method that changes boolean from false to true. Knockout does bind with HTML on page load, but there seems to be a problem with data bind on click event.

Observable does change when I debug the code, but View stays the same.

Whole code and (not)working example are down below.

```js
function ViewModel (data) {
 
 var self = this;
 
 this.textFlag = ko.observable(false);
 
 this.changeText = function (eventID, panelStatus) {
  this.textFlag = ko.observable(false);  
  
  if(eventID == 1) this.textFlag(panelStatus);
 }
}

var viewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<h1 data-bind="text: textFlag() === true"></h1>
<button data-bind="click: changeText(1, true)">Button</button>
```

See example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jtdzed8k/5/)

Comment: See Durga's edit, you can make your live example **right here on site**, instead of offsite in a fiddle, most of the time.

Comment: Please explain what you want to do in a bigger context. It's obvious where your mistake is and what to do to resolve it, but that's still not using knockout properly. There likely is a better way to achieve what you want to do, if you explain what this is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are redefining `this.textFlag` variable, thus breaking the binding. All you have to do is update its value using `this.textFlag(panelStatus);` like this :

```js
function ViewModel(data) {

  var self = this;

  this.textFlag = ko.observable(false);

  this.changeText = function(eventID, panelStatus) {
    if (eventID == 1) {
      this.textFlag(panelStatus);
    }
  }
}

var viewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<h1 data-bind="text: textFlag() === true"></h1>
<button data-bind="click: function () { changeText(1, true) }">Button</button>
```

As stated in TJ Crowder answer you also have to either wrap your call to your function inside another anonymous function as seen in [docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html) or create another function using bind like suggested.

Comment: (I'm very surprised that anonymous function works, I would have thought `this` would get lost. Been a while since I did significant KO work, and clearly it *does* work as your snippet works just fine. Huh.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I guess it was because we posted at the same time and showed both different issues, and yours seemed more relevant than mine to the downvoter. About the anonymous function, I mostly used KO like that, and as I said it is the way they show us in the docs.

Comment: (@T.J.Crowder I have to say I'm honored to surprise you :D)

Comment: Yeah. I have to admit I didn't catch the `textFlag` thing until I went back to add snippets (seeing that Durgo had made that so easy) and I was there saying "Um....why isn't it changing?" (And then eventually seeing it.) Anyway, good answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. @NathanP.

Answer (score 2):

Two issues:

1. You're *recreating* your observable in `changeText`. You need to remove the `this.textFlag = ko.observable(false);` line. You've already done that bit.
2. Your `click` handler is defined incorrectly. Remember that KO takes your bindings and effectively creates an object initializer out of them. Let's look at the one that would create:

   ```
   {
       click: changeText(1, true)
   }
   ```

   See the problem? That **calls** `changeText(1, true)` and assigns the **result** of the call to `click`. Instead, you want to provide a function reference, so `click` can call the function.

   *(Obviously, what KO actually does is more complicated than that, with lots of `with` wrappers, but eventually that's what it does.)*

Once you remove the errant line from `changeText`, you *could* do this:

```
<button data-bind="click: changeText.bind($data, 1, true)">Button</button>
```

Live Example:

```js
function ViewModel (data) {
 
 var self = this;
 
 this.textFlag = ko.observable(false);
 
 this.changeText = function (eventID, panelStatus) {
     
  if(eventID == 1) this.textFlag(panelStatus);
 }
  }

var viewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<h1 data-bind="text: textFlag() === true"></h1>
<button data-bind="click: changeText.bind($data, 1, true)">Button</button>
```

...but it may be better to define a function on the viewmodel that uses `1, true`:

```
this.changeText1True = function() { return this.changeText(1, true); };
```

...and call that:

```
<button data-bind="click: changeText1True">Button</button>
```

*(Obviously, use a better name.)*

Live Example:

```js
function ViewModel (data) {
 
 var self = this;
 
 this.textFlag = ko.observable(false);
 
 this.changeText = function (eventID, panelStatus) {
     
  if(eventID == 1) this.textFlag(panelStatus);
 }
  
  this.changeText1True = function() {
    return this.changeText(1, true);
  }
}

var viewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<h1 data-bind="text: textFlag() === true"></h1>
<button data-bind="click: changeText1True">Button</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
function ViewModel (data) {
 
 var self = this;
 
 self.textFlag = ko.observable(false);
 
 self.changeText = function (eventID, panelStatus) {
    
  if(eventID === 1) {
   self.textFlag(panelStatus);
  }
 }
}

var viewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<h1 data-bind="text: textFlag"></h1>
<button data-bind="click: changeText.bind($data, 1, true)">Button</button>
```

Made some change to your code.